# Devise refusing to let me log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

A bit ago I was following a set of instructions for how to implement usernames that one can sign in with in Devise. After implementing the code from the instructions I noticed that I was no longer able to sign in. Sign up, yes, but in no. Trying to sign in just results with a flash notice of an invalid login/password

The valid_user? method returns true so its not an issue of me being clumsy with remembering my password. I found a related problem being discussed here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plataformatec-devise/4RHM10yJFOw but nothing mentioned there solved my problem. Finally, I've override the create method of Devise::SessionsController to see step by step whats happening. I noticed there was something funky about the first line of it:

```
self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
```

which is outputting...

```
!! #<ArgumentError: uncaught throw :warden>
```

Anyone have any idea as to what might be happening here.

Instructions: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: Might sound crazy but are you sure your not already signed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some looking around I discovered that my problem was stemming from some code in my ApplicationController which is necessary in Rails 4 due to strong params.

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
```

I'd initially included :username and :email in the list of permitted attributes rather than the login field (virtual attr that can be username/email) which was what was included on the form. So, a silly mistake with an aggravatingly hard to track down solution.